# ggplot2 and chron barplot of time data scale_x_chron

Tags: r, time, ggplot2, chron

I have a number of times and want to plot the frequency of each time in a barplot

```
library(ggplot2)
library(chron)
test <- data.frame(times = c(rep("7:00:00",4), rep("8:00:00",3), 
                         rep("12:00:00",1), rep("13:00:00",5)))
test$times <- times(test$times)
test
      times
1  07:00:00
2  07:00:00
3  07:00:00
4  07:00:00
5  08:00:00
6  08:00:00
7  08:00:00
8  12:00:00
9  13:00:00
10 13:00:00
11 13:00:00
12 13:00:00
13 13:00:00
```

The value of `binwidth` is chosen to represent minutes

```
p <- ggplot(test, aes(x = times)) + geom_bar(binwidth=1/24/60)
p + scale_x_chron(format="%H:%M")
```

As you see the scales are plus one hour in the x-axis:

[image]

I have the feeling that is has something to do with the timezone, but I cant really place it:

```
Sys.timezone()
[1] "CET"
```

Edit:
Thanks @shadow for comment

UPDATE:

If I run `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')` first it works perfectly. The problem is in the `times()` function. I automatically sets the timezone to `GMT` and if I'm plotting the x-axis, ggplot notices that my system-timezone is `CET` and adds one hour on the plot. 
Now if i'm setting my system-timezone to `GMT`, ggplot doesn't add an hour.

Comment: Take a look at some of the challenges of working with timezones here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156015/posixct-to-numeric-using-different-timezones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that `times(...)` assumes the timezone is GMT, and then `ggplot` compensates for your actual timezone. This is fair enough: times are meaningless unless you specify timezone. The bigger problem is that it does not seem possible to tell `times(...)` what the actual timezone is (if someone else knows how to do this I'd love to know).

A workaround is to use POSIXct and identify your timezone (mine is EST).

```
test <- data.frame(times = c(rep("7:00:00",4), rep("8:00:00",3), 
                             rep("12:00:00",1), rep("13:00:00",5)))
test$times <- as.POSIXct(test$times,format="%H:%M:%S",tz="EST")
p <- ggplot(test, aes(x = times)) + geom_bar(binwidth=60,width=.01)
```

[image]

`binwidth=60` is 60 seconds.

Comment: Is it possible to use a `scale_x_...` for `POSIXTct`, say for setting limits? Because everytime I was using `scale_x_datetime`, the date appeared and I just wanted to limit my x-axis without the appearance of dates. This was one of the reasons I switched to the `chron`-package.

Comment: You could add `scale_x_datetime(labels=date_format("%H:%M"))`, but there's no need in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It has nothing to do with timeszone, the only problem is that in `format`, `%m` represents the month and `%M` represents the minute. So the following will work

```
p + scale_x_chron(format="%H:%M")
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing the mistake but still doesn't work: http://imgur.com/yHvxQxr. The hours are still +1.8:00 instead of 7:00, for example.

Comment: Try setting your R system timezone to be the same as the data were originally. For example, for UTC data, use `Sys.setenv(TZ='GMT')`.